# Migrating From ASP.NET Web Form .NET 3.5 to MVC 4.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, migration, asp.net-membership, membership

I have a plan to convert and migrate my old project from asp.net webform 3.5 to mvc 4.0.
I want to know  if it is possible to do not make any changes on my existing customised membership (from net 3.5) on my new project (mvc 4.0) ? Any advices are welcome.

Comment: You are the one who knows about your customized membership so you can determine how big will be the changes or if migration has impact to it. If you wrote it in a class library or some sort of reusable class then MVC4 can probably use it as long as you didn't reference DLL to that membership where MVC4 cannot support or not appropriate for it to use it.

Comment: So do you think the membership on MVC 4 is still compatible with membership on asp.net 3.5 ?